# Is it possible to build up an inhouse APNs server?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am planning to build up an enterprise iOS/Android application. And I want to benefit from the Push Notification (for Android, it is called Google Cloud Messaging). However, our devices will not connect to the Internet, but Intranet through Wifi.Thus, we are not able to use the standard APNs or GCM provided by Apple or Google.

I am just wondering it is possible to build up a private APNs Server? And any open source library available. Or if there isn't any. Where can I buy one?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just an idea: pretend to be push.apple.com through the DNS server. Its very hard to imitate the push communication, because it's SSL encrypted.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible. I think you have to through the official channels, but maybe a hybrid approach could help you, such that a very minimum of data gets pushed. Essentially push "now" when client receives "now" do a pull from your servers on wifi, assuming your goal is to save bandwidth.

Comment: Actually, my goal is NOT to save bandwidth. My goal it to have my private APNs Server located inhouse. So I can get rid of APNs provided by Apple. I dont have Internet connection (only Intranet) at all.

Comment: You could just implement a comet poller yourself. It is not very complicated. Tons of comets have been implemented for the web

Answer (score 0):

For Apple iOS, you cannot buy one because the core OS uses certificates to make sure it's connecting to Apple's APN servers.

Because Google Android is open source, you can modify the core system to connect to your own APN network.  But your biggest problem will be making a binary and installing on the different hardware that is out there.

Comment: I agree with you that iOS is impossible. So I start to looking into Android.